# pywinauto - how click in text element in grid

Tags: pywinauto

I need given one click in text inside the grid, and not have click method in this element, how do it?

```
select_viagem = flight_app.child_window(title="166,80", control_type="Text")
select_viagem.click()
```

https://github.com/reinaldorossetti/pywinauto/blob/master/exemplo01.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/reinaldo.rossetti/PycharmProjects/pywinauto/exemplo01.py", line 56, in <module>
    select_viagem.click()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 171, in __call__
    format(self.criteria[-1]['best_match']))
AttributeError: WindowSpecification class has no 'click' method

    test = {UIAWrapper} <pywinauto.controls.uiawrapper.UIAWrapper object at 0x0000000005BE14E0>
 _abc_cache = {WeakSet} <_weakrefset.WeakSet object at 0x00000000050DF748>
 _abc_negative_cache = {WeakSet} <_weakrefset.WeakSet object at 0x00000000050DF7B8>
 _abc_negative_cache_version = {int} 39
 _abc_registry = {WeakSet} <_weakrefset.WeakSet object at 0x00000000050DF6D8>
 _as_parameter_ = {NoneType} None
 _cache = {dict} {}
 _control_types = {list} <class 'list'>: []
 _element_info = {UIAElementInfo} <pywinauto.uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo object at 0x0000000005BE16A0>
 _needs_image_prop = {bool} False
 actions = {_StandardLogger} <pywinauto.actionlogger._StandardLogger object at 0x0000000005BE1780>
 appdata = {NoneType} None
 backend = {BackEnd} <pywinauto.backend.BackEnd object at 0x00000000050DF828>
 can_be_label = {bool} False
 element_info = {UIAElementInfo} <pywinauto.uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo object at 0x0000000005BE16A0>
 friendlyclassname = {NoneType} None
 handle = {NoneType} None
 has_title = {bool} True
 iface_expand_collapse = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pywinauto\\uia_defines.py", line 217, in get_elem_interface\n    iface = cur_ptrn.QueryInterface(cls_name)\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\comtypes\\__init__.py", line 1
 iface_grid = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pywinauto\\uia_defines.py", line 217, in get_elem_interface\n    iface = cur_ptrn.QueryInterface(cls_name)\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\comtypes\\__init__.py", line 1
 iface_grid_item = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pywinauto\\uia_defines.py", line 217, in get_elem_interface\n    iface = cur_ptrn.QueryInterface(cls_name)\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\comtypes\\__init__.py", line 1
 iface_invoke = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pywinauto\\uia_defines.py", line 217, in get_elem_interface\n    iface = cur_ptrn.QueryInterface(cls_name)\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\comtypes\\__init__.py", line 1
 iface_item_container = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pywinauto\\uia_defines.py", line 217, in get_elem_interface\n    iface = cur_ptrn.QueryInterface(cls_name)\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\comtypes\\__init__.py", line 1
 iface_range_value = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pywinauto\\uia_defines.py", line 217, in get_elem_interface\n    iface = cur_ptrn.QueryInterface(cls_name)\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\comtypes\\__init__.py", line 1
 iface_scroll_item = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pywinauto\\uia_defines.py", line 217, in get_elem_interface\n    iface = cur_ptrn.QueryInterface(cls_name)\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\comtypes\\__init__.py", line 1
 iface_selection = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pywinauto\\uia_defines.py", line 217, in get_elem_interface\n    iface = cur_ptrn.QueryInterface(cls_name)\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\comtypes\\__init__.py", line 1
 iface_selection_item = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pywinauto\\uia_defines.py", line 217, in get_elem_interface\n    iface = cur_ptrn.QueryInterface(cls_name)\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\comtypes\\__init__.py", line 1
 iface_table = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pywinauto\\uia_defines.py", line 217, in get_elem_interface\n    iface = cur_ptrn.QueryInterface(cls_name)\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\comtypes\\__init__.py", line 1
 iface_table_item = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pywinauto\\uia_defines.py", line 217, in get_elem_interface\n    iface = cur_ptrn.QueryInterface(cls_name)\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\comtypes\\__init__.py", line 1
 iface_text = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pywinauto\\uia_defines.py", line 217, in get_elem_interface\n    iface = cur_ptrn.QueryInterface(cls_name)\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\comtypes\\__init__.py", line 1
 iface_toggle = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pywinauto\\uia_defines.py", line 217, in get_elem_interface\n    iface = cur_ptrn.QueryInterface(cls_name)\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\comtypes\\__init__.py", line 1
 iface_value = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pywinauto\\uia_defines.py", line 217, in get_elem_interface\n    iface = cur_ptrn.QueryInterface(cls_name)\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\comtypes\\__init__.py", line 1
 iface_virtualized_item = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pywinauto\\uia_defines.py", line 217, in get_elem_interface\n    iface = cur_ptrn.QueryInterface(cls_name)\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\comtypes\\__init__.py", line 1
 iface_window = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pywinauto\\uia_defines.py", line 217, in get_elem_interface\n    iface = cur_ptrn.QueryInterface(cls_name)\n  File "C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\comtypes\\__init__.py", line 1
 ref = {NoneType} None
 windowclasses = {list} <class 'list'>: []
 writable_props = {list} <class 'list'>: ['class_name', 'friendly_class_name', 'texts', 'control_id', 'rectangle', 'is_visible', 'is_enabled', 'control_count', 'is_keyboard_focusable', 'has_keyboard_focus']
```

send this logs.

Comment: What `select_viagem.wrapper_object()` returns?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov <bound method WindowSpecification.wrapper_object of <pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification object at 0x0000000005C400B8>>

Comment: It's a value of `select_viagem.wrapper_object`, not a `select_viagem.wrapper_object()`. Please don't mess function object and function call.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've tried this app on my machine and it works so (on your locale dot should be replaced with comma):

```
grid.child_window(title="131.10", control_type="Text").click_input()
```

The grid elements have no `InvokePattern` so that method `.invoke()` will raise `NoPatternInterfaceError`. Method `.click()` is just an alias of `.invoke()` for buttons. But it may have different meaning for other control types. That's why we use `.invoke()` name only for non-button controls.

Comment: I have problem: flight_app.child_window(title="131.10", control_type="Text").click_input() // pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': '131.10', 'control_type': 'Text', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <pywinauto.uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo object at 0x0000000004018048>, 'backend': 'uia'}

Comment: grid.child_window(title="131.10", control_type="Text").click_input()  ---> pywinauto.findwindows.ElementAmbiguousError: There are 7 elements that match the criteria {'backend': 'uia', 'control_type': 'Custom', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <pywinauto.uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo object at 0x00000000044D0978>, 'title': 'Item: FlightsGUI.Logic.GuiFlight, Índice de Exibição de Coluna: 0'}

Comment: Did you read the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)? It explains how to use spy (inspect) tools and how window specifications and wrapper objects work. In your second comment it looks like you have 7 items with the same text. But I'm curious why it prints `'control_type': 'Custom'` that conflicts with `control_type='Text'` search criterion.

Comment: This title is unique, no have another 7 elements equal. This is the same of your example.

Comment: Do not have a way to choose which element of 7?
Example:
Element = grid.child_window (title = "131.10", control_type = 'text') [0]
Element.click_input ()  --> this example not work.

Comment: You can add `found_index=0` or up to `found_index=6` into search criteria for `child_window` specification.

Comment: Sorry for delayed replies. Too busy for more detailed investigation.